# Multiple sql conditions based on checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing an advanced search system which searches users according to their skills. These are the various skills.

[image: skills]

Each skill is stored in separate column in database with values 0 & 1.
Now when I am searching for a user I am using `OR` criteria so that when I check Access the users with Access skill would be found. Here is the code for the search criteria:

```
$query .= "SELECT * FROM wordpress_candidate
WHERE (city = '$cty')
OR (state = '$stt')";
if(isset($s_g_1)){  $query .=  "OR (generala = '$s_g_1')";    }
if(isset($s_g_2)){  $query .=  "OR (generalb = '$s_g_2')";    }
if(isset($s_g_3)){  $query .=  "OR (generalc = '$s_g_3')";    }
if(isset($s_g_4)){  $query .=  "OR (generald = '$s_g_4')";    }
//if(isset($s_g_5)){  $query .=  "OR (generale = '$s_g_5')";    }
if(isset($s_g_6)){  $query .=  "OR (generale = '$s_g_6')";    }
if(isset($s_g_7)){  $query .=  "OR (generalf = '$s_g_7')";    }
if(isset($s_g_8)){  $query .=  "OR (generalg = '$s_g_8')";    }
if(isset($s_g_9)){  $query .=  "OR (generalh = '$s_g_9')";    }
if(isset($s_g_10)){  $query .=  "OR (generali = '$s_g_10')";    }
if(isset($s_g_11)){  $query .=  "OR (generalj = '$s_g_11')";    }
if(isset($s_g_12)){  $query .=  "OR (generalk = '$s_g_12')";    }
if(isset($s_g_other)){  $query .=  "OR (generall = '$s_g_other')";    }
if(isset($s_f_1)){  $query .=  "OR (funda = '$s_f_1')";    }
if(isset($s_f_2)){  $query .=  "OR (fundb = '$s_f_2')";    }
if(isset($s_f_3)){  $query .=  "OR (fundc = '$s_f_3')";    }
if(isset($s_f_4)){  $query .=  "OR (fundd = '$s_f_4')";    }
if(isset($s_f_5)){  $query .=  "OR (funde = '$s_f_5')";    }
if(isset($s_f_6)){  $query .=  "OR (fundf = '$s_f_6')";    }
if(isset($s_f_7)){  $query .=  "OR (fundg = '$s_f_7')";    }
if(isset($s_f_8)){  $query .=  "OR (fundh = '$s_f_8')";    }
if(isset($s_f_9)){  $query .=  "OR (fundi = '$s_f_9')";    }
if(isset($s_f_10)){  $query .=  "OR (fundj = '$s_f_10')";    }
if(isset($s_f_11)){  $query .=  "OR (fundk = '$s_f_11')";    }
if(isset($s_f_12)){  $query .=  "OR (fundl = '$s_f_12')";    }
if(isset($s_f_13)){  $query .=  "OR (fundm = '$s_f_13')";    }
if(isset($s_f_other)){  $query .=  "OR (fund = '$s_f_other')";    }
if(isset($s_a_1)){  $query .=  "OR (acca = '$s_a_1')";    }
if(isset($s_a_2)){  $query .=  "OR (accb = '$s_a_2')";    }
if(isset($s_a_3)){  $query .=  "OR (accc = '$s_a_3')";    }
if(isset($s_a_4)){  $query .=  "OR (accd = '$s_a_4')";    }
if(isset($s_a_5)){  $query .=  "OR (acce = '$s_a_5')";    }
if(isset($s_a_6)){  $query .=  "OR (accf = '$s_a_6')";    }
if(isset($s_a_7)){  $query .=  "OR (accg = '$s_a_7')";    }
if(isset($s_a_8)){  $query .=  "OR (acch = '$s_a_8')";    }
if(isset($s_a_9)){  $query .=  "OR (acci = '$s_a_9')";    }
if(isset($s_a_10)){  $query .=  "OR (accj = '$s_a_10')";    }
if(isset($s_a_11)){  $query .=  "OR (acck = '$s_a_11')";    }
if(isset($s_a_other)){  $query .=  "OR (accl = '$s_a_other')";    }
if(isset($s_p_1)){  $query .=  "OR (puba = '$s_p_1')";    }
if(isset($s_p_2)){  $query .=  "OR (pubb = '$s_p_2')";    }
if(isset($s_p_3)){  $query .=  "OR (pubc = '$s_p_3')";    }
if(isset($s_p_4)){  $query .=  "OR (pubd = '$s_p_4')";    }
if(isset($s_p_5)){  $query .=  "OR (pube = '$s_p_5')";    }
if(isset($s_p_6)){  $query .=  "OR (pubf = '$s_p_6')";    }
if(isset($s_p_7)){  $query .=  "OR (pubg = '$s_p_7')";    }
if(isset($s_p_8)){  $query .=  "OR (pubh = '$s_p_8')";    }
if(isset($s_p_9)){  $query .=  "OR (pubi = '$s_p_9')";    }
if(isset($s_p_other)){  $query .=  "OR (pubj = '$s_p_other')";    }
if(isset($s_i_1)){  $query .=  "OR (ita = '$s_i_1')";    }
if(isset($s_i_2)){  $query .=  "OR (itb = '$s_i_2')";    }
if(isset($s_i_3)){  $query .=  "OR (itc = '$s_i_3')";    }
if(isset($s_i_4)){  $query .=  "OR (itd = '$s_i_4')";    }
if(isset($s_i_5)){  $query .=  "OR (ite = '$s_i_5')";    }
if(isset($s_i_6)){  $query .=  "OR (itf = '$s_i_6')";    }
if(isset($s_i_7)){  $query .=  "OR (itg = '$s_i_7')";    }
if(isset($s_i_8)){  $query .=  "OR (ith = '$s_i_8')";    }
if(isset($s_i_other)){  $query .=  "OR (iti = '$s_i_other')";
```

This code is working perfect but if both Access And Crystal are checked I want to search users according to both criteria but it only searches according to one . I know I can check condition for both check boxes and add AND in query. But how can I do this for all the checkbox?

HTML

```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="searchform" action="">
<tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_1=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_1" name="s_g_1" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_1"><span>Access</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_1=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_1" name="s_f_1" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_1"><span>ACT</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_1=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_1" name="s_a_1" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_1"><span>Blackbaud Financial Edge&nbsp;</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_1=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_1" name="s_p_1" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_1"><span>Corel Draw</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_1=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_1" name="s_i_1" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_1"><span>Mac</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_2=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_2" name="s_g_2" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_2"><span>Crystal Reports&nbsp;</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_10=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_10" name="s_f_10" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_10"><span>Convio</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_2=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_2" name="s_a_2" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_2"><span>Fund EZ</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_8=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_8" name="s_p_8" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_8"><span>Dreamweaver</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_2=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_2" name="s_i_2" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_2"><span>PC</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_3=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_3" name="s_g_3" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_3"><span>Excel</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_2=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_2" name="s_f_2" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_2"><span>Donor2</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_3=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_3" name="s_a_3" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_3"><span>Fundware</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_2=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_2" name="s_p_2" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_2"><span>Front Page</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_3=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_3" name="s_i_3" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_3"><span>Web</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_4=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_4" name="s_g_4" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_4"><span>Filemaker Pro</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_3=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_3" name="s_f_3" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_3"><span>Donor Perfect</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_11=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_11" name="s_a_11" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_11"><span>Great Plains</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_3=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_3" name="s_p_3" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_3"><span>Illustrator</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_4=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_4" name="s_i_4" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_4"><span>Windows XP</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_11=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_11" name="s_g_11" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_11"><span>HTML</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_11=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_11" name="s_f_11" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_11"><span>eTapestry</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_4=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_4" name="s_a_4" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_4"><span>MIP</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_9=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_9" name="s_p_9" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_9"><span>InDesign</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_5=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_5" name="s_i_5" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_5"><span>Help Desk</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_6=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_6" name="s_g_6" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_6"><span>Lotus</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_4=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_4" name="s_f_4" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_4"><span>Fundmaster</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_5=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_5" id="" name="s_a_5" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_5"><span>OneWrite Plus</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_4=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_4" name="s_p_4" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_4"><span>Pagemaker</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_6=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_6"name="s_i_6" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_6"><span>Oracle</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_7=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_7" name="s_g_7" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_7"><span>Outlook</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_5=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_5" name="s_f_5" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_5"><span>GiftmakerPRO&nbsp;</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_6=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_6" name="s_a_6" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_6"><span>Peachtree</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_5=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_5" name="s_p_5" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_5"><span>Photoshop</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_7=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_7" name="s_i_7" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_7"><span>Windows NT</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_8=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_8" name="s_g_8" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_8"><span>Powerpoint</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_12=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_12" name="s_f_12" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_12"><span>GIFTS</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_7=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_7" name="s_a_7" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_7"><span>Quickbooks</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_6=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_6" name="s_p_6" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_6"><span>Quark</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_8=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_8" name="s_i_8" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_8"><span>Windows 2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_12=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_12" name="s_g_12" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_12"><span>Salesforce</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_5=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_5" name="s_g_5" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_5"><span>iMIS</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_8=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_8" name="s_a_8" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_8"><span>Quicken</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_7=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_7" name="s_p_7" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_7"><span>MS Publisher&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_i_other=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_i_other" name="s_i_other" type="checkbox"><label for="s_i_other"><span>Other</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_9=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_9" name="s_g_9" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_9"><span>Word</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_6=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_6" name="s_f_6" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_6"><span>Millenium</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_9=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_9" name="s_a_9" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_9"><span>Real World</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_p_other=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_p_other" name="s_p_other" type="checkbox"><label for="s_p_other"><span>Other</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_10=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_10" name="s_g_10" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_10"><span>Word Perfect</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_7=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_7" name="s_f_7" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_7"><span>Paradigm</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_10=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_10" name="s_a_10" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_10"><span>Solomon</span></label></td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_g_other=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_g_other" name="s_g_other" type="checkbox"><label for="s_g_other"><span>Other</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_8=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_8" name="s_f_8" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_8"><span>Pledgemaker</span></label></td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_a_other=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_a_other" name="s_a_other" type="checkbox"><label for="s_a_other"><span>Other</span></label></td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_9=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_9" name="s_f_9" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_9"><span>Raiser's Edge&nbsp;</span></label></td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left"><input value="1" <?php echo ($s_f_other=='1')?'checked':'' ?> id="s_f_other" name="s_f_other" type="checkbox"><label for="s_f_other"><span>Other</span></label></td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand, that you only want to filter users for checked skills. If a checkbox is not checked, it does not matter, whether the user has the skill or not; correct?

Here you filter only for the positive skills:

```
if ($s_g_1) {  $query .=  " AND (generala = 1) "; }
if ($s_g_2) {  $query .=  " AND (generalb = 1) "; }
...
```

So if 'Access' and 'Crystal' are selected, you get all Users that have both skills (`AND`), regardless of their other skills.

(I don't check with `isset()` in the if condition - I only want the condition in my query, if `$s_g_1` is not `0` (= if the checkbox is checked). If you don't know, whether `$s_g_1` is defined, check it with `!empty($s_g_1)` to avoid a `NOTICE`.)

Comment: okay a question i want each field like this so `WHERE (city = '$cty')";` how can I make this also available  when variable is set `$cty`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` clause instead of `OR` to search for both

```
if(isset($s_g_1)){  $query .=  "AND (generala = '$s_g_1')";    }
if(isset($s_g_2)){  $query .=  "AND (generalb = '$s_g_2')";    }
```

Also I suggest, Use a loop to check these all.

Comment: I'm 2 minutes late. :) I'll just point out that using his query, he is already looking for those who have both skills, among those who have only one of the two. With your answer, he will find only those who possess all the skills selected.

Comment: If i use `AND` it checks for unchecked values also but I need if both are checked only than `AND` should work. Please read the question.

Comment: It shouldn't use unchecked values. If it does, I think the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Try like this  : `if(isset($s_g_1) && $s_g_1){` You can use trim or whatever to ensure to concatenate string in query.

Comment: yes but there are too many of them. How will I able to check all of them?

Comment: can you also share your html ?

Comment: I suggest to use name as array and value=`your current name of checkbox` and use loop in php too, after creating array.

Comment: okay a question i want each field like this so `WHERE (city = '$cty')";` how can I make this also available  when variable is set `$cty`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an Input to select search of type "and" or "or"

```
$query .= "SELECT * FROM wordpress_candidate
WHERE (city = '$cty')
OR (state = '$stt')";
if (searchType = 'AND')
{
    $and_or = 'AND'
}
else 
{
    $and_or = 'OR'
}
if(isset($s_g_1) && ($s_g_1)) {  $query .=  $and_or + " (generala = '$s_g_1')";    }
if(isset($s_g_2) && ($s_g_2)) {  $query .=  $and_or + " (generalb = '$s_g_2')";    }
```

Comment: can the condition check itself when two or more are selected?

Comment: I think that you need another input for choose type of search. If that is not valid for you, you can count checks that are checked.

Comment: okay a question i want each field like this so `WHERE (city = '$cty')";` how can I make this also available  when variable is set `$cty`?